# .htaccess Redirect language requests/prettify URLS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a php based site and I'm making use of a `lang` URL variable which controls the current page's language. But it looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page?lang=en # Yes, I am using .htaccess to remove the php extension from php pages.
```

So I want to rewrite it with .htaccess like this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/page # Doesn't this look way better?
```

Keep in mind that I am not and do not want to rely on `Accept-Language`, I want to give the user freedom to change the language even if their PC is in English, they could be natives to one of the languages my site has...

I tried the following approach:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ru/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|ru|de)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But that obviously relies on what the browser sends as a `Header` and thus it's not viable. It also breaks my site if I try to change to a language that is not within the `Accept-Language` - mine is English so if I try to visit the Deutsch version of the site I get this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/?lang=de
```

And that is certainly not what I want.

**EDIT:**

Actually that's what I found:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
```

I just had to do it for all of my pages... On problem is that if I try to do the following:

```
http://www.example.com/?lang=bg
```

It will remain like this and will not redirect so I had to change all my links as well -.- Any ideas on how to redirect? I already have the virtual URLs.

Comment: Those rules wouldn't even accomodate for `q=` quality parameter. The first language isn't necessarily the preferred one. -- Anyway, don't do this per RewriteRules. Probe ACCEPT_* headers in PHP, set a preference cookie accordingly, or have them overriden per `?lang=` param only when unset. (Also please use literal cookies, that's what they're for, not sessions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
```

Try this

Comment: That was what you put in your edit and said that it is working

Comment: Yes I just added the `RewriteCond`s on top of the rules I already have and it works!